# How to update JSON each Tuesday once in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an app that with the help of volley gets JSON Data, and instead of sending the request to get the new JSON each time the users opens the app, I want it to automatically update on Tuesdays, the catch is I only want Volley to GET the request only once each Tuesday of every week, so when he re-opens it on the same Tuesday it won't GET a new request. My question isn't code related, so I won't be posting code, but will do if you asked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).  It will run your your code at a specific time. For more details, see this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Only do your GET in when the alarm goes off and not when your app launches.  You may need to grab a wifi wake lock while in your alarm code to keep the device awake for network activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer !